# Deserialize XmlElements to nested complex type

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization

Is there a way to deserialize XmlElements to nested complex objects. I'm trying to have URL, Username, and Password populate the ServiceProvider.Properties object. Currently all the values are null.

```cs
public class ServiceProvider 
{
   [XmlElement("ID")]
   public SettingId SettingId { get; set; }

   public Properties Properties { get; set; }    
}

public class Properties
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Username { get; set; }

   [XmlElement]
   public string URL { get; set; }

   [XmlElement]
   public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class SettingId 
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Domain { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

```xml
<ServiceProviders>
    <ServiceProvider>
      <ID>
          <Key>Key</Key>
          <Domain>Domain</Domain>
          <Type>Type</Type>
      <ID>
      <URL>URL</URL>
      <Username>User</Username>      
      <Password>Password</Password>
  </ServiceProvider>
</ServiceProviders>
```

Comment: Thanks for your replay but that's how I have it coded now and the values are null in the properties object.

Comment: Your XML is invalid. Btw `</ID>`

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'Properties' tag in your XML. Instead remove that and just add the fields from that class into the ServiceProvider class. Make sure you have a `XMLRoot("ServiceProviders")` that has this class as a field

```
public class ServiceProvider 
{
    [XmlElement("ID")]
    public SettingId SettingId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string URL { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your example is how I had it originally and it was working.  I was hoping to transform those values into a Properties object during deserialization.  Basically taking those elements and mapping them to a complex nested object.  I assume it's not possible without writing custom deserialization code.  Thanks for your reply

Comment: @kamce why would you want to do that?

Comment: It's the way the current class is defined.  I was just trying to coerce it to that format without have to add a different class and then map to the existing class.